# How to reduce tx size using typed Plutus script with Vasil fork PlutusV2?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, transaction

With the recent Vasil fork script references allow to reduce transaction size. Even though Vasil has been already launched on the testnet I could not find information on how to reduce the size of typed Plutus scripts. The only lead I have found is [this](https://github.com/james-iohk/plutus-scripts) repository, but it only has examples on how to use PlutusV2 with untyped scripts.

How to reduce tx size using typed Plutus script with Vasil fork PlutusV2?

Comment: https://github.com/perturbing/vasil-tests/blob/main/referencing-scripts-cip-33.md. Here is an example of a typed plutus script V2.

Answer (score 1):

The common understanding is that reference scripts & reference inputs allow for making some transactions smaller as they would not need to include the full script when spending an output governed by a Plutus script.

Comment: Yes I know, but for that AFAIK you need PlutusV2 code, which typed scripts I can't find!

Comment: I don't think that reference scripts dictate use of PlutusV2, but the library / framework you use to create transactions needs to support these features.

For example: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/9f1d7dc163ee66410d912e48509d6a2300cfa68a/cardano-api/src/Cardano/Api/Script.hs#L1410-L1417 in the cardano-api library.